# Ubuntu 9.10/Compiz swap windows on workspaces (like taskbar shuffle for workspaces)

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, workspace, gnome-panel, shuffle

How can I move all the windows on one workspace to another workspace (all at once)? It doesn't seem to be possible from the gnome-panel applet (workspace switcher).

Separately, can start me on the way of writing this software (like taskbar shuffle for xp) for ubuntu? I'm guessing it's written in  c/c++?

Answer (score 1):

The command [`wmctrl`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) can move individual windows between workspaces.  You could write a script (in `bash`, `perl`, etc.) that parses its listing (`wmctrl -l`) and then moves all of the windows on one workspace to another.  Its output is quite regular, e.g.

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x01a00019 -1 chef xfce4-panel
0x0300001a -1 chef x-nautilus-desktop
0x04e467f8  0 chef Edit - Super User - Google Chrome
0x05600003  2 chef swedish@chef: ~
0x056002ce  1 chef swedish@chef: ~
0x05603304  0 chef swedish@chef: ~
```

First column is the window ID (which you supply to other commands); second column is the 0-based workspace number.

`wmctrl` is available via [the eponymous ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/wmctrl).

You could even write a wrapper script that takes a direction (up, down, left, right) and moves all windows from the current workspace to the one in that direction, and then bind it to something like <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-{arrow}.

Answer (score 0):

One by one, you can right-click on the windows you wish to move and select "Move to Another Workspace". Or if you're a keyboard shortcut fan, `Shift+ Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right Arrow`.

[Another keyboard shortcuts are a good option too](http://www.hungry-hackers.com/2009/03/keyboard-shortcuts-for-ubuntu.html).

(It seens you want to move ALL windows with a single command. I don't know a way to do it, just windows by window)

Comment: yeah i'm definitely looking to move them all at once, thanks though.